# Laravel - Carbon Convert Meridian Time to DateTime

Tags: php, laravel

I have this DateTime format.

```
2016-11-22 12:04 PM
```

I want to convert it to UTC datetime which can be inserted into MysQL.
Can somebody please tell how to do it with **carbon**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your timezone and add this code something like this.Hope this will be helped you.

```
$timestamp = '2016-11-22 12:04 PM';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i A', $timestamp, 'America/New_York');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
```

Comment: I found out a way using strtotime(). But this would work too, I suppose.